# asymmetric page number

Tags: page-numbering

I am using article, twosided environment with geometry package. I set my margins asymmetrically - one of them is 5cm to make marginnotes. The problem is that page numbers are not in the center of the page, but in the center of the \textwidth. How to tell latex to set page numbering in the middle of the page ?

Comment: If you are not going to print on both sides, use `oneside` option (it is the default one).

Comment: What are you using to set your headers/footers to print the page number? Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we can replicate your current setup?

Comment: Can be easily done with `scrlayer-scrpage` -> `textwithmarginpar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is the package `scrlayer-scrpage` with option `footwidth=paper:<offset>`. If the inner margin is 2cm the offset is -2cm.

```
\documentclass[
  twoside
]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  inner=2cm,
  outer=5cm,
}

\usepackage[footwidth=paper:-2cm]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% KOMA-Script version 3.14 or newer
%\cfoot[\pagemark]{pagemark}% alternatively

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\Blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works with both oneside and twoside mode.

---

Or you can define a new layer even if you do not know the size of the inner margin.

```
\documentclass[
  twoside
]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  hmarginratio=1:3
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  width=\paperwidth,
  hoffset=0pt,
  foreground,
  contents={\makebox[\layerwidth]{\pagemark}}
]{pagenumber.fg}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.fg}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{pagenumber.fg}
%% or with one command to all pagestyles, including empty
%\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{pagenumber.fg}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using `geometry`; if you also load `fancyhdr`, it's easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=2cm,
  right=5cm,
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{3cm}% 5cm - 2cm

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Packages that write content in the header/footer are typically bound by the text block location on the page. If you wish to avoid this restriction and set page numbers based on the page, then [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) provides a simple solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,eso-pic}
\geometry{
  twoside,
  margin=2cm,
  inner=5cm,
  outer=2cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{3\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[\paperwidth]{\thepage}}
  }
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

You'll set `\thepage` at shipout (the appropriate time to do so) using lower left part of the page as a start (`\AtPageLowerLeft`).